# Print console logs in color using perl

Tags: perl

I am using below to print text in color at terminal

```
use Term::ANSIColor;
print color("red"), "Error\n";
```

But I am getting output as:

```
←[31mError
```

Is there anything else I need to do to print text in color or any other way?

Comment: What operation system are you on? And what terminal? That should work.

Comment: Though it would not reset the color with this, and the terminal would stay red until some other program resets it. Better use `print colored("Error\n", 'red')`

Comment: I am on windows server 2012 and using cmd.exe

Answer (score 3):

Are you on a Windows OS? From http://search.cpan.org/~rra/Term-ANSIColor-4.03/lib/Term/ANSIColor.pm -

> This module will not work as expected on displays that do not honor
>   these escape sequences, such as cmd.exe, 4nt.exe, and command.com
>   under either Windows NT or Windows 2000. They may just be ignored, or
>   they may display as an ESC character followed by some apparent
>   garbage.

Your output shows that the escape sequence is being added, but the console/terminal cannot display them.

Loading this module before Term::ANSIColor might help:
http://search.cpan.org/~jlmorel/Win32-Console-ANSI-1.10/lib/Win32/Console/ANSI.pm

Also, a relevant discussion on perlmonks: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=429607